# глобально изменить переменную C#

Tags: c#

Дело в том что у меня изменяется глобальная переменная внутри блока try, но другой блок не хочет видеть ее изменения. Изменял банально `x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` что делать в таком случае?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TicTac
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string Center(string str) { 
          return (String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(" ", (Console.WindowWidth / 2 - (str.Length / 2)))) + str);
        }
        static string welcome = "Игра крестики нолики"; 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x;
            int y;
            int type;
            string[][] map = new string[][] {
                new string[] {" ", " ", " "},
                new string[] {" ", " ", " "},
                new string[] {" ", " ", " "}
            };


            for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
            {

                    if (i % 2 == 0){

                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                        Console.Write("O ");
                    }
                    else{
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        Console.Write("X ");
                    }
                if (i % 3 == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(Center(welcome)+'\n');
            Console.WriteLine(Center("Чтобы выйти нажмите ESC"));
            while (Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar != 27) {
                try
                {
                    x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    type = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Это должно быть числом");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Environment.Exit(0);

                }
                try { 

                    char play;
                    switch (type) {
                        case 1:
                            play = 'x';
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            play = 'o';
                            break;
                        default:
                            play = ' ';
                            break;

                    }

                    map[y][x] = play.ToString(); 
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Переполнение");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < map.Length; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < map[i].Length; j++)
                    {
                        ;
                        if (map[i][j] == "x") Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red; else Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                        Console.Write(map[i][j] + " ");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. В шарпе нет глобальных переменных. 2. [mcve]?

Comment: Вот и воспроизведи мне сдесь С#

Comment: @Duoxx а что - в вопрос нельзя вставить C#-код, который потом, при желании, можно будет скопировать и запустить у себя локально? Да и не исключено, что уже по одному только виду кода будет понятно что с ним не так. А вы код не предоставили и хотите чтобы люди гадали на кофейной гуще?

Comment: Сдаётся мне, слово "минимальный" вы таки пропустили.

Comment: @Duoxx во-первых не грубите, а во вторых в шарпе и правда нет глобальный переменных. Подробнее опишите, что вы имеет ввиду. Тобишь код класс, в котором ваша глобальная переменная и метод, который пытается изменить эту переменную

Comment: @Duoxx хм, не уверен, что можно между try catch писать код. Попробуйте вынуть его оттуда. Во вторых - если можно, то область видимости в порядке.

Comment: Не грублю, так общаюсь.

Comment: Имхо вы зря отлавливаете исключения в своем коде, можно обойтись и без try-catch, используя метод Int32.TryParse https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы на счет присвоения переменной значения в блоке `try`, то переменная `x` - должна быть инициализирована:

```
int x = 0; // инициализация
try {
    x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
} catch {}
try {
    Console.WriteLine(x);
} catch {}
```

Comment: @Duoxx нет, переменная у вас была объявлена, но не была инициализирована.

Comment: @Duoxx посмотрие мой ответ. 
В вашей строке int x; нет инициализация, только объявление.
А вот инициализация int x = 0;

Comment: @Duoxx, https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level3/3_4.php

Comment: Извините объявлена, надо спать ложиться а то у меня уже 3 часа ночи (я на бали)

Answer (score 0):

Как писал @AresGod, x должна быть инициализирована.

Дело в том, что C# видит сценарий, когда блок Try не сработал, поэтому он показывает ошибку в сценарии, когда не сработал блок Try(тобишь переменной не присвоено значение).

Поэтому вам нужно в месте объявления проинициализировать переменную. А по хорошему засунуть в блок Try